# Verify if $\sum(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Verify if the series $\sum a_n$ with $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is
> convergent or divergent.

What I did is

$$a_n=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\times\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt
{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
$$<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}=b_n$$

Since $b_n$ is monotone decreasing and $b_n\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ then $b_n$ is convergent.

Using the comparison test, we have that $0\leq a_n\leq b_n$. If $b_n$ is convergent then $a_n$ is convergent.

Is it right?

Comment: You proved that the *sequence* $a_n$ converges to zero. However, this does not imply that *series* $\sum a_n$ converges. In fact, the series diverges since it is comparable to $\sum \frac {1}{\sqrt n}$ which is divergent since it is a $p$-series with $p \le 1$.

Comment: The title is about the sequence, and the quote box is about the series.

Comment: You should review your tests: having $b_n$ decreasing and converging to $0$ does not imply that $\sum b_n$ is convergent. The classic example is the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. The series $\sum \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ is another one.

Comment: @Taladris I made a confusion of one theorem for sequences and used it for series.

Comment: [This search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum(%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B1%7D-%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D)%24&p=1) and [this search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20(%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B1%7D-%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D)%24&p=1) in Approach0 return several similar questions.

Comment: [Does this series diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/962301),
[$\sum a_n = \sum{(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})}$ Prove divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1032430),
[Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/162434),
[Evaluate $\sum \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1661080)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The series diverges. This can be seen using the fact that it is a "telescoping series".

The $k^\text{th}$ partial sum can be written as follows:

\begin{align}
S_k &= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k \Big(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}\Big)\\\\
&= \big(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1}\,\big) + \big(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\,\big) + \big(\sqrt{4} - \sqrt{3}\,\big) + \cdots +\big(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}\,\big)\\\\
&=-\sqrt{1} + \big(\sqrt{2} -\sqrt{2}\,\big) + \big(\sqrt{3} -\sqrt{3}\,\big) + \big(\sqrt{4} - \cdots -\sqrt{k}\,\big) + \sqrt{k+1}\\\\
&=\sqrt{k+1} - 1\\
\end{align}

As $k$ goes to infinity, this diverges, so the infinite sum does not converge.

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}\Big) = \lim_{k\to\infty} S_k = \infty$$

Comment: Interesting, so if the kth partial sum diverges then the infinite series diverges? The theorem that I found just say about the convergence, then I'm not sure if it's valid for divergence.

Comment: @Roland An [infinite sum is *defined* as the limit of the partial sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)). So when I say the $k^\text{th}$ partial sum diverges as $k$ goes to infinity, that is actually by definition what it means for the infinite sum to diverge :)

Answer (score 6):

In the same manner,

$$a_n>\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac12\frac1{\sqrt {n+1}}>\frac12\frac1{\sqrt{n+n}}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\frac1{\sqrt n}=b_n$$

By the comparison test, we easily see that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n>\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\to+\infty$$

which follows from the p-series.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt {n}=$$

$$\sqrt {n}(\sqrt {1+\frac {1}{n}}-1)$$

$$\sim \sqrt {n}.\frac {1}{2n} $$
$$\sim \frac {1}{2\sqrt {n}} $$
the series diverges.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible to show  that
$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\left(\sqrt{j+1}-\sqrt{j}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{j}}}{2}\right)+2 \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}=-\sqrt{2}$$ although mathematics numerically does not calculate it well, and therefore $$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\sqrt{j+1}-\sqrt{j}\right)=-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: I don't believe your definition of a convergent series is the same as the OP's. Can you elaborate on how you got that result?

Comment: What you believe or stop believing is up to you, but mathematics is what it ia , voting negatively on an issue that is not understood is foolish but without wanting to be arrogant, it is something that you can look at WIKI about the analytical continuation.